# Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that $\int_{a}^b f=t-s$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Despite having looked at the many examples on here of proving (or disproving) that a function is Riemann integrable, I still can't quite wrap my head around how one would prove the following:

> Suppose $a\leq s<t\leq b$.  Define $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ by 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{if } s<x<t,\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and that $\int_a^b f=t-s$.

First I simply tried "unwinding" the definition that I am working with of what it means for a function to be Riemann integrable:

> If $f$ is a bounded function on a closed, bounded interval, then $f$ is Riemann integrable if its lower Riemann integral equals its upper Riemann integral.

Ok, so the lower Riemann integral is defined as $$L(f,[a,b])=\sup_PL(f,P,[a,b])=\sup_P\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f$$
and the upper Riemann integral is defined as $$U(f,[a,b])=\inf_PU(f,P,[a,b])=\inf_P\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f$$ where both are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$.  So I want to show that $$L(f,[a,b])=t-s=U(f,[a,b]).$$  But I don't know how!

Is there a standard approach to solving these types of problems?  I am certain I need to utilize some sort of $\epsilon,\delta$ argument here, but I am not very good with those types of proofs to begin with.  I'm not really looking for an answer as much as I am looking for *why* the answer would be written the way it is i.e. what is your thought process when you see one of these and how does that process help you to a solution?

Comment: The function only takes two values, and when it has value $1$ is really predictable.  Use this to get your upper and lower sums.

Comment: Discuss the positional relation of $(x_j)_0^n$ and $s,t$, e.g. what if some $x_k$ satisfies $s < x_k < t < x_{k+1}$? What about other cases?

Comment: Use the definition of Riemann integral based on Riemann sums.

Comment: $U(f,P)$ should be able to be calculated quite easily for any partition $P$. Thus $U(f, [a,b])$ should also be easily recovered. $L(f,[a,b])$ is a little trickier. You should find that $L(f,P)\leq t-s$ for any partition $P$ (just write it out). Now you just need to show that $\sup_P L(f,P)=t-s$ (if you don't/can't use zhw's method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $a<s<t<b.$ Consider $U(f,P_n)- L(f,P_n)$ for the partition $P_n=\{a,s-1/n,s+1/n,t-1/n,t+1/n,b\}$ for large $n.$

Comment: Here the norm of partition does not tend to $0$. I think you intended to have a partition which divides each of $[a, s], [s, t] $ and $[t, b] $ into $n$ parts so that the whole $[a, b] $ is divided into $3n$ parts and then we take limits as $n\to\infty $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think zhw has the $U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon$ equivalent definition in mind which doesn't care about mesh size.

Comment: @RobertWolfe: yeah this does show that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: @RobertWolfe Sorry to comment so late, but what is "mesh size?"  Also, what is the $U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon$ definition?

Comment: @ThyArtisMath a function is integrable if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. zhw is providing a sequence of partitions that will eventually procure you such a partition. "mesh size" or simply "mesh" or "norm of partition" of a partition $P=\{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is defined as $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})$.

Comment: @RobertWolfe Oh, ok.  That makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, then this partition can be of two types ($\underbrace{s\mbox{ and }t \in P}_{Type 1})$ or ($\underbrace{s \mbox{ or } t \not \in P}_{Type 2}$)

Then if $P$ is of Type1, $L(f,P,[a,b])=t-s$ because out of the interval $[s,t]$ we have $f(x)=0$ and hence $\inf f(x)=0$. In a same way you can show that $U(f,P,[a,b])=t-s$ too.

If $P$ is of Type2, you can see (and prove) that $L(f,P,[a,b])\leq L(f,P',[a,b])$ for any $P'$ of Type1. So, you can affirme (why?) that $\sup \limits_P L(f,P,[a,b])=\sup \limits _{P'}L(f,P',[a,b])$, where the first sup is taken over all $P$ and the second is taken over all $P'$ that are of type1.

Finaly, as we saw that the lower and upper sum using type1-partitions will always be the same constant, we conclude what we want!

Comment: It is sufficient to consider partitions of type 1 only and use definition of Riemann integral. using a Riemann sum is simpler here.